# Meaning of 'I'm about as angry as I've been in a long, long time'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I saw this headline somewhere.

> FBI Director Wray on shutdown: 'I'm about as angry as I've been in a
>   long, long time'.

But I got confused what the quotation means. How to analyze it?

- I haven't been so angry for a long time.
- The shutdown is too long and irritates me.
- I've been angry for a long time.

Which is correct or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first meaning is correct.

The second might be true, but was not said.

The third is certainly not what is meant.

The sentence has the

> as ... as ...

construction. For example

> I am as hungry as a horse.
>
> He is as cool as a cucumber.

and a bit more complex than

> I'm as angry as I've ever been.